# Managed c++ to clr __pin to pin_ptr or interior_ptr

Tags: c++-cli, clr, managed-c++

I am trying to compile a project that was previous using **/oldsyntax**, but now with **/clr**.

```
std::string Jhc::Interop::stlString(System::String^ s)
{
    std::string out;
    const wchar_t __pin * str = PtrToStringChars(s);
    int len = s->Length*4;
    char *buf = new char[len];
    memset(buf,len,0);
```

I have changed `System::String *s` to `System::String^ s`, but how do I covert the line with `PtrToStringChars(s);`?

I have tried using `pin_ptr` and `interior_ptr`, but cannot make it work.

Comment: Could you please show the compile error?

Comment: Maybe you want to turn it into a `std::wstring` instead?  If not, then you need to do a locale conversion from wide-characters to UTF8.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Comment: I think I have  solved it by using : pin_ptr<const wchar_t> str = PtrToStringChars(s);

Comment: I found it on msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx